# In Batch Normalization we normalize the test input every layers or only the first layer

Tags: machine-learning, batch-normalization

We know that batch normalization will normalize the net activations $z_n^{(l)*}$ for each layer. But I am not sure how to normalize the input of test? Here we ignore the final step of scaling and shifting in Batch Normalization.

Suppose $\{z_1^{(l)*},\cdots,z_N^{(l)*}\}$ is the net activation of entire samples under trained parameters with mean $\mu^{(l)*},$ variance $(\sigma^{(l)*})^2.$ Then for a test input $x,$ do we have:

$$x\rightarrow \hat{x}=\dfrac{x-\mu^{(0)*}}{\sigma^{(0)*}}\Rightarrow  x^{(1)} \rightarrow \hat{x}^{(1)}=\dfrac{x^{(1)}-\mu^{(1)*}}{\sigma^{(1)*}}\Rightarrow  x^{(2)} \rightarrow \hat{x}^{(2)}=\dfrac{x^{(2)}-\mu^{(2)*}}{\sigma^{(2)*}}\Rightarrow \cdots$$

or

only normalize at begin:
$$x\rightarrow \hat{x}=\dfrac{x-\mu^{(0)*}}{\sigma^{(0)*}}$$
and no further normalizations in the later layers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch normalization isn’t a yes-or-no decision for the entire network. You can apply it (or not) after each layer. Each layer maintains its own mean and variance; the two statistics are computed from the current batch.

With that in mind, if you include a BatchNorm layer only after the input layer, your second equation is correct. If you include a BatchNorm layer after every single layer, then your first equation is correct.

At test time, you *don’t* use the test set’s statistics. You use the saved statistics from the training set. But that seems orthogonal to the question you’re really asking.

Comment: So the conclusion is that, the layers normalized in test should be consistent with the layers in normalized in training.

Comment: Yep, that’s right!

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is correct, batch normalization is applied at each layer. The only difference between train and test time is that *at test time*, the running estimates of the mean and variance are not updated.